# The Hierarchy of “collections” for Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

When we deal with usual *category* $\mathbf A$ we require that *Ob*$(\mathbf A)$ (i.e., collection of objects of category $\mathbf A$) and *Mor*$(\mathbf A)$ (i.e., collection of morphisms between objects in category $\mathbf A$) form a class (*proper* or no).

Then if we deal with *metacategory* $\mathbf A$ we say that *Ob*$(\mathbf A)$ is a *conglomerate* and *Mor*$(\mathbf A)$ so is.

To form a *conglomerate* we require:

1. every class is a *conglomerate*,
2. for every “property” *P*, one can form the *conglomerate* of all classes with property *P*,
3. *conglomerates* are closed under analogues of the usual set-theoretic constructions, and
4. the *Axiom of Choice for Conglomerates*; namely for each surjection between *conglomerates* $f:X\rightarrow Y$, there is an injection $g:Y\rightarrow X$ with $f\circ g=id_Y$.

So the question is: can we continue this hierarchy further to form the *metacategory of all metacategories* and so on?

Comment: This use of the term "quasicategory" is horribly archaic; please avoid it.

Comment: Mike is too polite to self-advertise, but he wrote a great exposition on (set-theoretical) foundational issues in category theory: https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279

Comment: @Myself, i’ve never seen this paper, so i’ll check it!

Comment: You should also be careful with the adjective "regular" here. Perhaps "usual" would be more appropriate. It's not a big deal, but I was a bit puzzled at first.

Comment: @ArnaudD., thank you, I edited this moment!

Comment: _Metacategory_ is perhaps a suitable alternative to the ambiguous term "quasicategory".

Comment: @DavidRoberts, now I checked the references and saw that term quasicategory is now being used in different meaning. So yes, _metacategory_ is more suitable.

Comment: @A. I have edited to refer to metacategories, and also fixed the list markdown syntax

Comment: If one takes "can we continue" in this OP to be roughly the same as "do we still have well-defined operations at our disposal", then [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120084/what-kinds-of-operations-are-well-defined-when-working-with-sets-classes-congl) definetely is very relevant (and was heretofore unlinked). A recommendation in an answer in that thread is roughly the same as 'Myself''s, i.e., to read [M. Shulman: *Set theory for category theory*. arXiv:0810.1279](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279).

Comment: @PeterHeinig, yes, I’ve talked about the operations which I mentioned in my question, so you are right.